# Order of member initialization list

Tags: c++, initialization, member-initialization

After simplifying my code for many times, I found the following cause the problem.

```
class B {
public:
    B(const int x)
              :_x(x) {}
    const int _x;
};

class C {
public:
    C(const B& b) 
        : _b(b), _b2(_b._x) {}
    B _b2;       // line 1
    const B& _b; // line 2
};

int main() {
    B b(1);
    C c(b);
}
```

Warning (clang 8.0.0)

```
test16.cpp:11:22: warning: reference '_b' is not yet bound to a value when used here [-Wuninitialized]
        : _b(b), _b2(_b._x) {}
                     ^
1 warning generated.
```

g++-6 compiles the program. Running the program causes segmentation fault.

Does the initialization of members of a class follows the order of the member initialization list (`: _b(b), _b2(_b._x)`) or the order of the members in the class (like `B _b2; const B& _b;`) ?

Comment: Before I simplify the code, _b2 was a public member and _b was a private member. I usually write public section before private section ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialization of member variables occurs in the order that they are declared in the class.

http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-order

and:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.

Comment: Kind of difficult to choose which answer to accept. I trust the isocpp. So I pick this one in the end.

Comment: @rxu I use www.cppreference.com extensively for work and research. It is worth a bookmark.

Answer (score 3):

The order how you specify in the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order) doesn't matter, non-static members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.

> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.

That means `_b2` will always be initialized before `_b`; and when `_b` is used to initialize `_b2` it's still not initialized.

BTW: The similar rule is applied for the initializations of direct base classes.

> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list

Comment: I haven't had the luck to have point 2) to cause trouble for me yet. Yet it is very good to know this now.